# Lightning-map is not getting updated as I am updating the map-marker through JS in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, google-map

**On a click of a button I am setting the latitude and longitude in the map-marker but lightning-map is updating/refreshing.**
Here is the code:
HTML:

```
<template>
<lightning-button label='Click' onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
    <lightning-map
        map-markers={mapMarkers}
    >
  </lightning-map>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class Lwc_map extends LightningElement {

   
    @track mapMarkers=[];

    handleClick(event){
        this.mapMarkers={
            location: {
                Latitude: '28.535517',
                Longitude: '77.39103',
                
            }
        
        }
        window.console.log('Set'+ JSON.stringify(this.mapMarkers));
    }
}
```

**Pls,suggest me method how i can update lightning-map on a click in lwc.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mapMarkers is an array so you should put the content like this

```
 this.mapMarkers = [...this.mapMarkers, {
            location: {
                Latitude: '28.535517',
                Longitude: '77.39103',
                
            }
        
        }];
```

Comment: Thanks User6670.

Comment: I am using your provided way in a location showing app but its not updating the map.

Comment: @jegoxab   it works for me may be you can put your whole code